Creme Brulee disaster - Any way to recover?
I made a batch of Creme Brulee in my Sous Vide bath last night (82C for 1 hour in a ziploc bag), 6 egg yolks, 600ml cream, 6 tablespoons of sugar and vanilla essence. Normally, this turns out firm but wobbly, after 12 hours in the refrigerator it is still runny.
Why has this happened and is there anything I can do with this dessert to rescue it?
